# I want to display input field text using js

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code just began learning so dont know what am i doing wrong. Help!!

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type = "text" placeholder = "Number One" id = "one"></input><br>
<input type = "text" placeholder = "Number Two" id = "two"></input><br>
<button onclick = "test()">Click Me</button><br>
<script>
function test()
{
document.getElementById("one").value;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are getting the value but thats all. whats do you want to do rest? Alert it? console log? innetHTMl?

Comment: i want to display the result. either in alert or in any form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Here**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=1f62bd6606084603b5ee62c002767e5c) shows that its working. All you have to do is assing a function to show the value.

JS

```
function test()
{
var x = document.getElementById("one").value;
  alert(x);
}
```

Comment: You can also grab an element set its text to value of one by using innetHTML. After you grab lots of things to do with ;)@JenishMaharjan

Comment: Guney Saramali Thanks for the Tips ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Look at your html, it should be

```
<input type = "text" placeholder = "Number One" id = "one"/><br />

<input type = "text" placeholder = "Number Two" id = "two"/><br />
```

You can put an alert, or console.log in your script tag to know if its being hit e.g.

```
    <script>
    function test() {
        alert('function called');
        document.getElementById("one").value;
    }
</script>
```

Thanks.